# how to display <li></li> tag only after login

Tags: php

I am trying to display the logout button only if any user is logged in.

following is the code:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['user']))  
     { echo '<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</li>'; }
?>
```

But it is giving error.
Error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'logout' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 42
Help me to display this link.

Comment: I cannot see an error message.

Comment: "it is giving error" — How about you tell us what error it is giving?

Comment: I have aadded the error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use unescaped `'` characters in string literals delimited by `'` characters. Either:

- Use `"` instead
- Escape the `'`
- Drop out of PHP mode and just write the HTML as normal template code

Such:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
?>
          <li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</li>
<?php
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your quotes and opening them again. Try this:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
         echo '<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</li>';
     }
?>
```

Note the double quotes.

Alternatively, escape the quotes like this:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
         echo '<li><a href=\'logout.php\'>Logout</li>';
     }
?>
```